# How to make Galileo thermometers?

Tags: temperature, density, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Is it possible to create a [Galileo thermometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_thermometer) by hand with household items? What are the physics and mathematics behind the Galileo thermometer and how can I solve them to use different densities of liquids?

I want to attempt to create a Galileo thermometer (or a few if possible) as a science project that uses various liquids that have different densities at specific temperatures. I understand the fundamentals of how the thermometer works and at this point, I am stuck on how to accurately adjust the weights on each globe to affect their temperature reading. Is there a formula for dealing with this? Or is the liquids in the globes different per globe and that is what makes them float or sink inside the main liquid and not the weight of the tag?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.juliantrubin.com/encyclopedia/physics/galileo_thermometer.html      not sure if it's  too basic for you or if you have already read it.

Comment: The effective density is (mass of float + mass of tag)/(volume of float + volume of tag). Since the tag is a more dense material, you just have to start with it too heavy and trim (or file) it until it has neutral buoyancy at a desired temperature.The globes are sealed, so their mass and volume are fixed

Comment: Oops, I hit ENTER. The volume of the float also will change due to thermal expansion. The thermometer won't work if the liquid and float have the same coefficient of expansion.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Is there a way to calculate the desired and/or approximate mass for the tag, or is this trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

If
$M =$ mass of float
$V = $volume of float
$m =$ mass of tag
$\rho =$ density of tag
$D =$ density of liquid
then
$$D =\frac{M + m}{V+m/\rho} $$